# Cython buffer declarations for object members

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I want to have a Cython "cdef" object with a NumPy member, and be able to use fast buffer access.  Ideally, I would do something like:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class Model:
  cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] A

  def sum(self):
    cdef int i, s=0, N=len(self.A)
    for 0 <= i < N:
      s += self.A[i]
    return s

  def __init__(self):
    self.A = np.arange(1000)
```

Unfortunately, Cython can't compile this, with the error `Buffer types only allowed as function local variables`.

The workaround I'm using is to declare the buffer attributes on a new local variable, assigned to the object member:

```
cdef class Model:
  cdef np.ndarray A

  def sum(self):
    cdef int i, s=0, N=len(self.A)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] A = self.A
    for 0 <= i < N:
      s += A[i]
    return s
```

This becomes really annoying if you want to have multiple methods accessing the same data structures -- which seems like a pretty common use case, no?

Is there a better solution that doesn't require re-declaring the types inside every method?

Answer (score 14):

There is the option to work with memory slices or cython arrays
http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

  cdef class Model:

    cdef int [:] A

    def sum(self):

        for 0 <= i < N:
            s += self.A[i]
        return s

    def __init__(self):
        self.A = np.arange(1000)
```

Comment: When you use this memoryviews approach, you may lose performance ?? I profile this : stringsource:368(__dealloc__) and  stringsource:341(__cinit__). By the way, this is also discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056696/when-profiling-cython-code-what-is-stringsource

Comment: What is the elegant solution about this requirement issue?

Answer (score 6):

The solution that you are currently using is what I tend to use, i.e. make a local copy in the function. It's not elegant, but I don't think you take a huge performance hit (or at least in my case, I'm doing a lot of work in the method, so it doesn't make a discernible difference). I've also created a C-array in the __cinit__ method and then filled it with the data in __init__ (make sure you use __dealloc__ to clean-up properly). You lose some of the features of the numpy array, but you can still use it as you would a c-array.

You might also check out the discussion in this older email on the cython list:

http://codespeak.net/pipermail/cython-dev/2009-April/005214.html