# cython optimization of class methods dismal in comparison to function

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to implement a simple rolling average in cython. I'm running this through very large data sets as part of an algorithm simulation so using pandas.rolling etc is not an option.

However, I'm facing a really vexing situation where cython is really not performing well on class methods. The following is the code.

```
class RollingAverage:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.current = 0
        self.ma = 0
        self.window_length = length
        self.window = np.zeros(length, dtype=np.float32)

    def mean(self):
        return self.ma

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    def update(self, value):
        self.ma += (value - self.window[self.current % self.window_length]) / self.window_length
        self.window[self.current % self.window_length] = value
        self.current += 1
        return self.ma

    def update2(self,value):
        self.ma = __update_impl( self.ma,
                                 self.current,
                                 self.window_length,
                                 self.window,
                                 value )
        self.current += 1
        return self.ma

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def __update_impl(ma, current, window_length, window, value):
    ma += (value - window[current % window_length]) / window_length
    window[current % window_length] = value
    return ma
```

I also have a pxd file in which the following is defined:

```
cdef class RollingAverage:
    cdef int current
    cdef float ma
    cdef int window_length
    cdef np.ndarray window
    cpdef update(self, float value)
    cpdef update2(self, float value)
    cpdef mean(self)


cdef float __update_impl(float ma,
                  int current,
                  int window_length,
                  np.ndarray[float] window,
                  float value)
```

**Edit:** here is the cython annotate difference of the hot code in both `update` and `__update_impl`:

```
def update(self, value):

+0127:      self.ma += (value - self.window[self.current % self.window_length]) / self.window_length

  __pyx_t_1 = PyFloat_FromDouble(__pyx_v_self->ma); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 127, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_2 = PyFloat_FromDouble(__pyx_v_value); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 127, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  if (unlikely(__pyx_v_self->window_length == 0)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError, "integer division or modulo by zero");
    __PYX_ERR(0, 127, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __pyx_t_8 = __Pyx_mod_int(__pyx_v_self->current, __pyx_v_self->window_length);
  __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_GetItemInt(((PyObject *)__pyx_v_self->window), __pyx_t_8, int, 1, __Pyx_PyInt_From_int, 0, 0, 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(0, 127, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_4);
  __pyx_t_6 = PyNumber_Subtract(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_4); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_6)) __PYX_ERR(0, 127, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_6);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_4 = 0;
  __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_int(__pyx_v_self->window_length); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(0, 127, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_4);
  __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyNumber_Divide(__pyx_t_6, __pyx_t_4); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 127, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_6); __pyx_t_6 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_4 = 0;
  __pyx_t_4 = PyNumber_InPlaceAdd(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_t_2); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(0, 127, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_4);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __pyx_t_7 = __pyx_PyFloat_AsFloat(__pyx_t_4); if (unlikely((__pyx_t_7 == (float)-1) && PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 127, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_4 = 0;
  __pyx_v_self->ma = __pyx_t_7;

+0129:      self.current += 1
+0130:      return self.ma


def __update_impl(ma, current, window_length, window, value):

+0146:  ma += (value - window[current % window_length]) / window_length

  if (unlikely(__pyx_v_window_length == 0)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError, "integer division or modulo by zero");
    __PYX_ERR(0, 146, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_mod_int(__pyx_v_current, __pyx_v_window_length);
  __pyx_t_2 = (__pyx_v_value - (*__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(float *, __pyx_pybuffernd_window.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_1, __pyx_pybuffernd_window.diminfo[0].strides)));
  if (unlikely(__pyx_v_window_length == 0)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ZeroDivisionError, "float division");
    __PYX_ERR(0, 146, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __pyx_v_ma = (__pyx_v_ma + (__pyx_t_2 / ((float)__pyx_v_window_length)));

+0147:  window[current % window_length] = value
+0148:  return ma
```

The method `update` is almost an order of magnitude slower than `update2`.

```
%%timeit
ma.update(1000)
The slowest run took 11.68 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3 µs per loop

%%timeit
ma.update2(1000)
The slowest run took 22.90 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 416 ns per loop
```

Furthermore, when I run "cython -a" on the source, I get some seriously spurious stuff in the method while the function has not a trace of yellow in it, compiling down almost entirely to C code.

I have also attempted replacing all `self.` variables with local variables which I declare in cython, to no avail. For some reason, having code in a method forces a slew of tests and conversions.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried removing the decorators `@cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)`?

Comment: Yes, I just edited the post. If you mean around `update2`,  it makes no difference. I just checked around `update` and that makes no difference either.

I'm going to further edit the post and show what cython annotate gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key difference is `ndarray[float]` in the quick version Vs `ndarray` in the slow version. Without knowing the array data type it's impossible for Cython to do any real optimisation to access.

You've had to do this because [fully typed ndarrays aren't allowed as class members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808216/cython-buffer-declarations-for-object-members). The best solution is to use a typed memoryview instead `float [:]` which does largely the same thing. (If you specifically need to access the ndarray to call one of its methods for example then you can get it via the `.base` attribute of the memoryview)

Comment: Ahh, fantastic. I knew about the `ndarray` short-coming when I originally coded this. I now see the interaction it is having with the compiler.

Can you clarify your point about `.base`? My understanding is that I would cdef a local variable to represent the `ndarray`, but is there any reason I would not directly access the `ndarray` should I need to?

Comment: So if you make `window` a typed memoryview you get fast indexing but don't get access to the functions that a ndarray has. So if you wanted to use one of them you'd have to do it as e.g. `window.base.sum()` (i.e. get the ndarray then call its function). I only mention it since it's the minor inconvenience of typed memoryviews but is easily avoided.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the quick response and solution.